# How to enable ScrollBar theme in eclipse 4.6 dark theme under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: eclipse, scrollbar, eclipse-neon

According to this,scrollbar color can be changed under eclipse 4.6 dark theme:

```
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php
```

I have added this:

```
-Dswt.enable.themedScrollBar=true
```

and change ..plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.100.v20160411-1921/css/dark/e4-dark_globalstyle.css 's

```
swt-scrollbar-themed: false;
```

to

```
swt-scrollbar-themed: true;
```

but nothing happened,so how to do it correctly?

**update:add a screenshot of eclipse**
[image]

Comment: You are looking at something that uses `StyledText` (such as an editor)? Scroll bars for other objects such as trees and tables are still not styled.

Comment: Thanks,I added a screenshot,as you can see that this scrollbar of pydev editor didn't got styled.

Comment: Everything apart from the editor is not StyledText so isn't styled. I don't know if this works for the PyDev editor which tends to do some unusual things. Try the plain text file editor.

Comment: Styling works as expected in xml editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll bar theme support currently only works for controls based on `StyledText`. So most text based editors, but not form based editors. It does not currently work for views based on trees and tables (support for this may be in Eclipse 4.7).

It looks like the pydev editor does not support the scroll bar theming.

Answer (score 0):

luckily I have stumbled upon the same issue long long time ago, it works! and it happens that it also works with eclipse neon. Surely you can have dark scrollbar style in the dark theme. (just have to add env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 to the startup file.

1) you can run it in terminal typing the following command:

```
env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 /home/willianma/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/eclipse&
```

(the default eclipse dark theme works with dark scrollbar, but if by any issues you may face you cannot get it working straightaway, you can alternatively download and install the eclipse moonrise theme (the one eclipse have taken the dark theme from).
It's available in http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/

via update site:
download this plugin by using Help > Install New Software... and add the update site:
https://raw.github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.updatesite

also can install RainbowDrops.epf from http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/

To add an desktop icon, follow the steps below:

Create a new desktop file called ‘eclipse.desktop’ in /usr/share/applications/

$ sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

– Then add the following lines to the above file and save

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 /home/YOUR_USER/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Development;Java;PHP;IDE;
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

– Run the following command to automatically install it in Unity

sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

– Create a symlink in /usr/local/bin

cd /usr/local/bin/

sudo ln -s /home/YOUR_USER/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/eclipse

– For Eclipse icon to be displayed in dash, run following command

sudo cp /home/YOUR_USER/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm

[scrollbar after applying those steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2TVI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that PyDev uses a subclass of StyledText called StyledTextWithoutVerticalBar, so, your steps are correct, but you also need to change the "e4-dark_globalstyle.css" so that the section related to customizing the StyledText reads:

```
StyledText, StyledTextWithoutVerticalBar {

    swt-scrollbar-themed: true;

    swt-scrollbar-background-color: #383838;
    swt-scrollbar-foreground-color: #494949;
    swt-scrollbar-width: 4px;
    swt-scrollbar-border-radius: 4px;
    swt-scrollbar-mouse-near-scroll-width: 15px;
}
```

(i.e.: applying the same style from StyledText to StyledTextWithoutVerticalBar).

As a note, if you use one of the themes from LiClipse (http://www.liclipse.com/change_color_theme.html), things work by default.